# How to loft surfaces along a guide curve in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a profile of a nacelle inlet for an engine and need to loft a curve along a circular arc to produce my surface. I cannot use sweep utility in splipy.surface_factory since the profile varies along the guide curve. Using splipy.surface_factory.loft does not allow me to use a guide curve.

```py
from splipy import curve_factory as cf
from splipy import surface_factory as sf
from splipy.io import STL

bezier_5 = cf.bezier([array2], quadratic=False, relative=False)
bezier_51 = cf.bezier([array3], quadratic=False, relative=False)
bezier_52 = cf.bezier([array4], quadratic=False, relative=False)
surface = sf.loft(bezier_5,bezier_51,bezier_52)
surface.refine(20)
with STL('temp.stl') as myfile:
    myfile.write(surface)
```

Comment: I would really appreciate any assistance!